# Jquery plugin for video player from third party video sites

Tags: jquery, video, jquery-plugins, video-streaming

I am offering users to share video links from various third party sites like youtube, vimeo etc.

I want to playback those videos on my site like [pintrest](http://pinterest.com/pin/101682904056667520/) and other websites are doing. I am not able to find out some free jquery plugin for this. [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) etc are solutions but they are not free.

Any suggestions?

PS: I dont want to have a modal box or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vimeo and YouTube both have embed APIs that you can use. So you could detect which service was used and then use the embed code for that service. For instance YouTube has a very easy-to-use `<iframe>` embed method that would require only a small bit of logic on your-end.

I've seen [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) used quite well but I don't think it does a Flash video fallback. Other than that I know [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) and [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) will work great but you have to pay to get rid of the logo (free if you don't mind the logo).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Jasper:

If you would like to use the iframe APIs of Youtube and Vimeo, you can use this jQuery widget: https://github.com/dachcom-digital/jquery-video It unifies the API methods for both video platforms

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an iframe in your HTML:

```
<iframe class="yl-inline-iframe" src="'+embedURL+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Update the embedURL with any Video ID in Javascript:

```
embedURL = "//www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+"?rel=0";
embedURL = "//player.vimeo.com/video/"+id;
//id is the video id
```